# Ideal architecture design for namespace parameters

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I have 3 header files

```
// a1.h
namespace a
{
  enum abc:uint8
  {
      abc1 = 1
      abc2 = 2
  };
}

// a2.h
namespace b
{
  enum abc:uint8
  {
      abc1 = 1
      abc2 = 2
      abc3 = 3
  };
}

// out.h
namespace out
{
  enum abc:uint8
  {
      abc1 = 1
      abc2 = 2
      abc3 = 3    
  };
}
```

I want to apply some operation `dosomething(a::abc, &out::abc)` or `dosomething(b::abc, &out::abc)` on the enum where I simply map input from (`a::abc` or `b::abc`) to output (`out::abc`) using switch statements. The easiest solution would be to write two separate functions for different namespaces.

I am wondering if the `dosomething` function can be templatized given that

1. Enum values are same (number of enum values are same e.g all have abc1, abc2)
2. Enum values are different (namespace b::abc::abc1 = 3, b::abc::abc2 = 4)
3. New enum value introduced (eg. b::abc::abc3)

This would avoid code duplication and make the design extendable.

I have constraint that I cannot modify header files.

Comment: It is not clear with the `dosomething` should do, and what you mean with **1.**  and **2.**

Comment: Please look at updated question

Comment: A better organisation would be to rationalise the three enumerated types into one. If you really must have to have them separate, I suggest sticking with separate conversion functions. A templated solution will be limited by your assumptions (e.g. that `a::abc1` and `b::abc1` both have the same numeric value as `out::abc::abc1`) and will break if either header file changes and breaks that assumption (even if you can't modify them, presumably someone can, and you'll need to cope with that).  Separately overloaded functions mean you can deal with each header separately.

Comment: I understand that  a templated solution will be limited by the assumptions that a::abc1 and b::abc1 both have the same numeric value as out::abc::abc1. However, can we still go ahead with template if input2 has extra enum e.g b::abc::abc4. In such case, we would need to map b::abc::abc4 to default value of output e.g out::abc::abc2

Comment: Something is not right here. In point 2 of "given that": `b::abc::abc2 = 4`, but the definition says the value is 2.

Comment: Could you explain why you cannot modify the header files? As part of that, who *can* modify the header files? What mechanism is in place to guarantee that, for example, adding a new value to `a::abc` will necessarily also add a corresponding value to `out::abc`?

Comment: Ideally, I do agree all enum values at input and output side could be kept same. However, if this restriction could not be removed at moment, I was just wondering if mapping can be generalised.

Comment: @Anonymous So are you saying that someone might add a value to `a::abc` that does not correspond to a value in `out::abc`? If you have no control over anything, it's very difficult to write logic that works in more than one context.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite doable with a `static_cast`, you don't need a separate function at all:

```
a::abc A = a::abc2;
b::abc B = b::abc3;

a::abc A2 = static_cast<a::abc>(B);
cout << A << " " << A2 << " " << B;
```

Outputs `2 3 3` as expected.

https://www.ideone.com/pKltlP